# Background slideshow- make pause between fadein/out?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background

I have a working background slideshow, but the images immidiately begin to fadeout after the fadein effect is complete. I want there to be a gap inbetween pictures where they are not fading in or out. Here's my code:

The html:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="slideshow">
<div id="slideshow"></div>
</div>
```

The css:

```
.slideshow {
background: #000;
display:block;
width:inherit;
height:inherit;
}
#slideshow {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display: block;
opacity: 0.0;
background-color: #000;
background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/400/cats/?1"), 
url("http://lorempixel.com/400/400/animals/?2"), 
url("http://lorempixel.com/400/400/nature/?3"), 
url("http://lorempixel.com/400/400/technics/?4"), 
url("http://lorempixel.com/400/400/city/?5");
background-size: cover, 0px, 0px, 0px;
-webkit-transition: background-image 3000ms linear;
-moz-transition: background-image 3000ms linear;
-ms-transition: background-image 3000ms linear;
-o-transition: background-image 3000ms linear;
transition: background-image 3000ms linear;
}
```

Here's my js:

```
$(function() {
$.fx.interval = -6000;
(function cycleBgImage(elem, bgimg) {
elem.css("backgroundImage", bgimg).delay(1000, "fx")
.fadeTo(3000, 1, "linear", function() {
$(this).fadeTo(3000, 0, "linear", function() {
var img = $(this).css("backgroundImage").split(","),
bgimg = img.concat(img[0]).splice(1).join(",");
cycleBgImage(elem, bgimg);
    });
  });
}($("#slideshow")));
});
```

Any help with making a stoptime between images would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: 1sec pause: `transition: 300ms 1000ms background-image;`

Comment: btw, you don't really need all those vendor prefixes for `transition` anymore

Comment: That only changes the time that the #000 background will stay before the images cycle. The image itself will not stay longer

Answer (score 2):

Change your delay : elem.css("backgroundImage", bgimg).delay(**1000**, "fx")

Example; change **1000** in **3000** then the image will stay for 3 seconds

Comment: This is what I thought too, but that only makes the blank, black background color between images stay longer. The images still immidiately cycle after the fading

Comment: I've altered all of the numbers similar to how you mentioned, and none of them will make the images stay put between fade in/out. I'm starting to think I should just have arrows on the side to click to change it. Do you have an easy way to do this?